# Finding all of the solutions to the trigonometric equation $\cos (t \Omega )=\frac{x}{a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have

> $$a \cos (t \Omega )=x$$

I want to solve it by hand for $t$: Now, by hand I did this:

$$\cos (t \Omega )=\frac{x}{a}.$$

Now I simply use $$\cos ^{-1}(\cos (t \Omega )).$$

Rearranging, I get $$t=\frac{\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}{\Omega },$$

Now using software to do the same simple calculations. and I get

$$\pm \frac{2 \pi  c-\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}{\Omega },$$ where $C\in \mathbb{Z}$

Now this makes me think that there is something that I have not fully understood. Where does $\pi$ times an integer come from and why?

Comment: Cosine is a periodic function and hence if your equation has a solution, then it has in fact infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Of course! Thank you!

Comment: Also, there are usually two solutions to $\cos x=r$ in $[-\pi,\pi]$. If $x=a$ is a solution, so is $x=-a$ ($\cos$ is even).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets look at an easier example:
$$\cos(t) = x$$
or even better
$$\cos(t) = 1.$$
If you want to solve this equation, any (good) software will tell you that $t = 0 + 2\pi c$ for $c \in \mathbb{Z}$. Why is this? Lets look at the graph of $\cos(t)$:

[image: Graph of $\cos(t)$]

Solving $\cos(t) = 1$ means asking 'For what $t$ is $\cos(t)$ equal to $1$?'. As you can see in the picture above, there are a lot of $t$s that satisfy this property. There is $t=0$, $t=2\pi$, $t = - 2\pi$, and so on. In general one can say that $t = 0 + 2\pi c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

In your case you would actually get
$$\cos^{-1}\left( \frac{x}{a} \right) = t\omega + 2\pi c$$
and then you can restructure that expression to get the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

The function $y \to \cos y$ has both a reflection symmetry
$$\cos (-y) = \cos y$$
and a translation symmetry
$$\cos (y + 2 \pi) = \cos y,$$
and in fact all symmetries are given by composing these.

Now, for $z$ in the image $[-1, 1]$, we can produce one solution of the equation
$$\cos y = z$$ by applying $\arccos$, giving the solution
$$y = \arccos z.$$
Since $\cos$ is injective on $[0, \pi]$ and $\arccos$ is (by definition) the inverse of the restriction of $\cos$ to this interval, $y = \arccos z$ is the unique solution $y$ in that interval; we often call this the *principal solution*.

On the other hand, if we apply the reflection symmetry, we can rewrite $\cos y = z$ as
$$\cos(-y) = z,$$
and applying arccos by construction gives the unique solution for which $-y \in [0, \pi]$, that is, for which $y \in [-\pi, 0]$, namely,
$$y = -\arccos z.$$

Similarly, if we apply a translation symmetry $k$ times, we can rewrite $\cos y = z$ as
$$\cos(y + 2\pi k) = z,$$
and again applying arccos gives the unique solution for which $y + 2 \pi k \in [0, \pi]$, that is, for which $y \in \left(-2 \pi k, -2 \pi \left(k + \frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$.

Combining these symmetries yields all solutions, and in particular if we substitute $y = t \Omega$ and $z = \frac{x}{z}$, a little more algebra shows that we get exactly the solutions produced by the CAS you consulted.